# Элементы карусели не помещаются в div

Tags: html, jquery, css

Всем привет!
Ситуация следующая: пользуюсь MaterializeCSS
Хочу сделать карусель из карточек. В принципе, все работает, но есть проблема: сами карточки имеют большую высоту, чем отведенный под них div.
В итоге, все это выглядит вот так (карточки кропаются, "футер" пропадает):
[image: пример]

Код:

```html
<div class="carousel">
    <div class="col s12 m6 carousel-item">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="https://materializecss.com/images/sample-1.jpg">
          <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p>I am a very simple card. Some text here, ololololo. Yep, a little bit more</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action">
          <a href="#">This is a link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<!--И еще пару раз то же самое-->
  </div>
```

Пробовал в CSS задавать height: 100% для этого элемента - все тщетно.

Сам слайдер:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавил атрибут  style="height: 650px;" и все заработало.
Не актуально.